# QT Creator (2.8.1) debugger on windows 7 for qtquick/C++

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

Hy,

i have installed qt 5.1.1 and QT Creator 2.8.1 to start learning QT Quick.
My only problem is i can not debug the c++ code!

If i hit F5 it always quits with "Not possible"-"No Debugger defined" (or something similar).
I have the Visual Studio Professional 2012 Edition installed (so there has to be a debugger on my maschine).

I also read "http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-debugger-engines.html" but this realy does not help, it only says: "On Windows supported debuggers are: CDB or GDB. But CDB will not be detecte automatically and you have to install it manually and install some Windows Debugging Tools and set a symbol server...", which i tryed, but my maschine quit the download installation of Windows Debugging Tools with some undefined error

(

Installation Failed: 
A problem occurred while installing selected Windows SDK components.

Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information.

Please attempt to resolve the problem and then start Windows SDK setup again. If you continue to have problems with this issue, please visit the SDK team support page at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=130245.

[SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Windows SDK Setup (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Stack:    bei SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)     bei SDKSetup.Product.SetupProduct(TaskMode taskMode, ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)      bei SDKSetup.ProductCollection.SetupProducts(TaskMode taskMode, DownloadManager downloadManager, ManualResetEvent cancelEvent)      bei SDKSetup.ConfigProducts.DoCurrentTask(TaskMode Task)

).

Than i thought lets try GDB. I downloaded MinGW Installer which run for 10 min.
And now???

So my question is : "How to set a debugger in qtCreator on Windows 7 (if Windows Debugging Tools are unavailable, or how to make them available)?"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Standalone Debugging Tools for Windows 8.1" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx (scroll down).

There are also the "Windows 7 Standalone Debugging Tools (also for Windows XP)", but I assume it's not working, because your installed Visual Studio 2012 is maybe too new. It states:

> Newer versions of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable can cause issues when installing the SDK for Windows 7. For more information, see support for the Windows SDK.

Comment: i deinstalled Visual Studio 2012 but it still does not work even with the Standalone iso. Any hints on how to setup GDB ?